# How can I change the mount point of an external hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, mountpoint

My external HDD currently automatically mounts at a certain name, let's say `/media/500GB hard drive`. I wish to make it mount at a different location, for example `/media/500GB_HDD`.

I have looked inside disk utility, and have been able to change the label of the partition, but not change the name of the mount point. I have attempted to unmount and remount in terminal:

```
$  sudo mount -t hpfs /dev/sdc2 /media/500GB_HDD/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

According to disk utility, the type is `HFS+`.

What can I do to change the hard drive's mount point?

Answer (score 1):

Use **hfsplus** as fs type instead of hpfs [hpfs for ntfs].

Answer (score 0):

For fat32 drives, Ubuntu uses the filesystem label as name for the mountpoint. I don't know if HFS+ even has filesystem labels or how to change them if it does, but that's the route I'd try to follow.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the label of the partition, but it hasn't seemed to change the mountpoint.

Comment: Pity, then I have no idea :(